# EBay API: getMostWatchedItems returning RequestError

Tags: ebay-api

Based on the API documentation of EBay:
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/CallRef/getMostWatchedItems.html

I made the following call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getMostWatchedItems xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services">
  <maxResults>3</maxResults>
</getMostWatchedItems>
```

With the following headers:

```
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL 967
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME getMostWatchedItems
X-EBAY-API-SITEID 15
Content-Type text/xml
```

But it returns the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<eBay>
    <EBayTime>2018-11-09 03:20:27</EBayTime>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <ErrorClass>RequestError</ErrorClass>
            <SeverityCode>1</SeverityCode>
            <Severity>SeriousError</Severity>
            <Line>0</Line>
            <Column>0</Column>
            <ShortMessage>
                <![CDATA[ Unsupported verb. ]]>
            </ShortMessage>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</eBay>
```

Does anyone encounter the same issue? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <getMostWatchedItemsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-11-09 18:23:12</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Unsupported API call.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>The API call "getMostWatchedItems" is invalid or not supported in this release.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>967</Version>
    <Build>18863825</Build>
</getMostWatchedItemsResponse>
```

It appears that getMostWatchedItems is not supported by the 967 version of the eBay API.

Comment: What headers did you use? May I know? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct headers. Your headers look like they're for the Shopping API, which this call (gMWI) is not part of.

For 1 thing, you don't use SiteID in gMWI. You use Global IDs.

Have a look at [this Merchandising API tutorial](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchandising/docs/Concepts/MerchandisingAPI_FormatOverview.html), especially the Standard Headers section.